# Can a wave be changed by another wave?

Tags: waves

So I'm just a last grade school student and don't have much of info about waves but this question has been on my mind for a while. Take a wave, a simple radio wave. If we send another radio wave, or any type of other wave, can the secondary wave change the information carried on the first one? I mean if a wave carries information, like some waves sent from earth to space in order to notice any existing aliens from earth, can a wave of any type change the information carried on the first one? And also can this secondary wave get the information on the first one and send the info back to the sender of the secondary wave.
Sorry if my question is kinda unclear. If it needs any clarifications, please tell me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electromagnetic waves, including radio waves, do not interact with each other. If two waves pass through the same point, they will emerge from that crossing completely unaffected. This is good, not least because it would be impossible to see anything if waves did interact (think about how many sources of light are crossing the path of sunlight on the way to Earth, for example). So, when two radio waves cross, no transfer of information occurs from one to the other.

If you happen to be standing on a spot where two waves are crossing, you will see *interference*, which is caused by the fact that exactly *when* the two waves cross (and not before or after), their waveforms add together. If you're using an antenna at this spot, it will receive signals from both of these waves at once, which will likely result in a garbled transmission. But this is not the same thing as interaction; though both waves transfer information to the antenna, one wave does not transfer information to the other.

Comment: Just a minor addition: if there are physical objects along the path where the two waves "cross", then there can indeed be an interaction. Such is the case for radio waves travelling past an antenna - the metal in the antenna sort of "takes up" the pattern of the wave and rebroadcast it back out at greatly reduced power. This mixing is how multi-element antennas work. PS's answer is what we would call the "free space" condition.